# Delphi with multi printer

Tags: delphi, printing

I have application needs to print on 3 printers
i save the printers names in a txt file
the problem is when the user disconnect and reconnect the printer ( usb printer )
it takes anew name or anther name and the printing get mixed up.

how i select the printer if the name changed ?

Comment: Can't you let the user tell you which printer to use

Comment: no even the user don`t know the names of the printer

Comment: The PRINTER shouldn't get a new name. The USB PORT may be re-allocated to a new port, but if you print using the printer's NAME then that shouldn't concern you. How does your actual code look for selection of printer to print to, and the actual printing you do?

Comment: Enumerate the printers and ask the user to pick one. Or show the printer setup dialog. Just as every other program does.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If it's a background job printing, then that solution isn't viable. But by saving the printer's NAME (from the Printers string list), then it should be possible to print to a specific printer without asking the user. I have never experienced that the printer's NAME changes when plugging it into a new USB port. The PORT may be different, but setting the Printers.PrinterIndex to the proper printer should elimnate dependency on port assignments.

Comment: this is what i get if the usb port is not changed yes the printer name is the same but if usb port changes the printer name changes and the old name is offline printer

Comment: You will have to show the code you use to get the printer names and how you attempt to (re-)select the printer. The printer name shouldn't change just because the USB port changes. Show some code, as well as what your code returns for printer names, and we may be able to help you. Until then we are merely stumbling in the dark...

Comment: @HeartWare The printer name should not change, but it also depends on the used printer and driver. Maybe this printer is not the right tool for this job. Maybe disconnect/connect of this printer needs a reconfigure of the system or application. And even changing the print medium (size, type) maybe needs a reconfigure of the application. All of this has to be eliminated or implemented in the application.

Comment: @SirRufo: Which is why I ask for the actual code. It may be that the saving/restoring of printer name need to take into consideration that the printer name for this particular printer/driver re-installs itself when the USB port changes, and assigns a name like "MyCompany Printer on USB1". If so, the program needs to eliminate the " on USB#" from the saving and later scanning for the printer among the printer names stored in Printers string list. Like I said - I haven't seen this happen, but that doesn't mean that it CAN'T happen. But in order to help, we need to see the actual code...

Comment: the printer i have is Epson pos printer . the code for selecting the printer is simple i get the names from my text file then search in the Printers string list to get the index of the printer then i print if i found it . the printer name changes by adding a number to the name . the 3 printer all the same model.

Comment: @SirRufo yes i have to reconfigure my application each time that happens but im search for a final solution

Comment: Okay - three printers of the same model may explain why it changes name. Can you list the names as they are just before you switch USB port, and what they are just after? Make a tiny program that lists all the printers found in the Printers string list and run it before and after switching USB port, and add the output from these two runs to your original question, then we'll see what (and if) we can do...

Comment: Sometimes you need to use the right tools and preserve the context. Get a network printerport with 3 usb ports and connect the printers. Each port has a defined context (you can switch that by your application). Connect to the printers via network and that should solve your random name changing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue with USB cameras. They also tend to just create another instance/entry for the device under windows with an appended number (example: Epson Blah Blah #1) as soon as the device is moved to another USB port.

The answer most probably lies in the Device Descriptors. More specifically the HardwareID of the device.

For a quick way to see a device's HardwareID go to Control Panel > Device Manager (if Win7 or above) then right-click on the device whether it be a USB Flashdrive or USB Camera. Click on properties and goto the "Details" tab. Change the "Property" value to "Hardware Ids". You will see the HardwareIDs

You can find more information on that here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj649944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The latter talks about the registry keys where you can also find the information of a device. The key would be:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\\\Device Parameters
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB

So if you can link HardwareIDs to a printer then you would be able to enumerate installed printers to compare with then select the one you want. So you will install a printer initially and let your application select that printer and save its HardwareID. Then everytime devices change on the PC you can just get the one that correlates to the initially installed printer.

I have not tested this as I am currently without two exactly same devices to make sure both don't have the same Hardware Ids.